# Can I assign a per-thread index, using pthreads?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, thread-local

I'm optimizing some instrumentation for my project (Linux,ICC,pthreads), and would like some feedback on this technique to assign a unique index to a thread, so I can use it to index into an array of per-thread data.

The old technique uses a std::map based on pthread id, but I'd like to avoid locks and a map lookup if possible (it is creating a significant amount of overhead).

Here is my new technique:

```
static PerThreadInfo info[MAX_THREADS]; // shared, each index is per thread

// Allow each thread a unique sequential index, used for indexing into per
// thread data.
1:static size_t GetThreadIndex()
2:{
3:   static size_t threadCount = 0;
4:   __thread static size_t myThreadIndex = threadCount++;
5:   return myThreadIndex;
6:}
```

later in the code:

```
// add some info per thread, so it can be aggregated globally
info[ GetThreadIndex() ] = MyNewInfo();
```

So:

1) It looks like line 4 could be a race condition if two threads where created at exactly the same time. If so - how can I avoid this (preferably without locks)? I can't see how an atomic increment would help here.

2) Is there a better way to create a per-thread index somehow? Maybe by pre-generating the TLS index on thread creation somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) An atomic increment would help here actually, as the possible race is two threads reading and assigning the same ID to themselves, so making sure the increment (read number, add 1, store number) happens atomically fixes that race condition. On Intel a "lock; inc" would do the trick, or whatever your platform offers (like InterlockedIncrement() for Windows for example).

2) Well, you could actually make the whole info thread-local ("__thread static PerThreadInfo info;"), provided your only aim is to be able to access the data per-thread easily and under a common name. If you actually want it to be a globally accessible array, then saving the index as you do using TLS is a very straightforward and efficient way to do this. You could also pre-compute the indexes and pass them along as arguments at thread creation, as Kromey noted in his post.

Comment: 1) Of course, thanks for clearing that up.
2) That's true - but unfortunately I want "read access" to info from any thread, to do aggregation periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Why so averse to using locks? Solving race conditions is exactly what they're designed for...

In any rate, you can use the 4th argument in pthread_create() to pass an argument to your threads' start routine; in this way, you could use your master process to generate an incrementing counter as it launches the threads, and pass this counter into each thread as it is created, giving you your unique index for each thread.

Comment: See this link for several examples of how to pass arguments to threads; scroll up from here for a code example that looks like exactly what you're asking for. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#PassingArguments

Comment: Why not locks...because the profiler shows the locks are taking up a fair bit of time, and I believe they can be unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know you tagged this [pthreads], but you also mentioned the "old technique" of using std::map.  This leads me to believe that you're programming in C++.  In C++11 you have std::thread, and you can pass out unique indexes (id's) to your threads at thread creation time through an ordinary function parameter.

Below is an example HelloWorld that creates N threads, assigning each an index of 0 through N-1.  Each thread does nothing but say "hi" and give it's index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

inline void sub_print() {}

template <class A0, class ...Args>
void
sub_print(const A0& a0, const Args& ...args)
{
    std::cout << a0;
    sub_print(args...);
}

std::mutex&
cout_mut()
{
    static std::mutex m;
    return m;
}

template <class ...Args>
void
print(const Args& ...args)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> _(cout_mut());
    sub_print(args...);
}

void f(int id)
{
    print("This is thread ", id, "\n");
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(f, i));
    for (auto i = threads.begin(), e = threads.end(); i != e; ++i)
        i->join();
}
```

My output:

```
This is thread 0
This is thread 1
This is thread 4
This is thread 3
This is thread 5
This is thread 7
This is thread 6
This is thread 2
This is thread 9
This is thread 8
```